# Date formulas in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, date

I have a delivery spreadsheet that contains a column with dates as well as other information.  Is there a formula that can be written that would remove a row of information after the entered day is five days past?

Comment: No, there is no formula that will remove a row.  You will need vba.

Comment: Furthermore, while you might consider using a *filter* to **hide** a row instead of completely removing it, the auto-filter feature of Excel works with fixed value, not formulas like _five days past_.

Comment: However, filtering raises two possible solutions although they are awkward. One is if you already have a column with the number of _past_ days (or if you can add such a column): you then can filter on this column being less than 5. Another way, more complex, is to use conditional format to highlight in some way (font colour or background colour) the cells where the entered day is five days in the past (less than `=NOW()-5`), then to filter out on that colour.

Comment: mind sharing any sample data/file to clarify which cell does the "entered day" & "information" is located? ( :

Comment: or try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1348244/auto-hide-unhide-all-rows-based-on-value-in-colum/1348256?noredirect=1#comment2020593_1348256).