# Auto Hide/Unhide all rows based on value in colum

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have "sheet2" in which data populates dependent upon what's entered into "sheet1". The data populated is either "N/A" or a particular statement.

In sheet2 I'd like any rows with "N/A" in Column G to auto hide and become unhidden if data in sheet1 is changed resulting in a change from "N/A".

I know VBA is probably my answer, but I have no knowledge/experience working with those.

Comment: Since you already an excel sheet with formulas.. mind sharing a sample file or data+formula in Sheet1&2 for a clearer view. ||   "Column G to auto hide and become unhidden" <--- IMHO select header > data > filter will work automatically without vba/formula.. but it only hides rows, not columns.

Comment: Can't share due to proprietary reasons, but I'll do my best to explain. 

Sheet 1 "Heading" is a questionnaire. I have the check boxes linked to a cell to indicate TRUE or FALSE if selected or not. Sheet 2 pulls data from Sheet 3, "Narrative" depending on what is selected in Sheet 1 (TRUE or FALSE). 

Example formula: 

=IF(OR(Headings!B6=TRUE,Headings!B7=TRUE,Headings!B10=TRUE,Headings!B11=TRUE),Narrative!C29,"N/A")

N/A populates quite a bit, and in stead of a full row of "N/A's", I'd like those rows to hide until they show something else.

Comment: So this is the formula contained in column G Sheet2.. right?

Comment: Yes. I figured I'd have to make a new Column G and put a formula like =h1 (h is old columng ) so it shows N/A or whatever and use that in the VBA.

Answer (score 1):

**Since you want Excel to automatically Hide & Unhide Row/Column if designated column contains #NA error/Value. So in that case VBA (Macro) is the best and handy solution.**

*Enter this code as standard module in 
 Sheet 2.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = [H2:H25]
    For Each cl In rng
        If IsError(cl) Then
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = cl = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Else
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = cl = ""
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- Adjust cell references in code as needed.
- My suggestion is instead of hide/unhide 
  Row better handle the formula Column 
  only.
- To hide Row replace,`cl.EntireColumn.Hidden` with `cl.EntireRow.Hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. put in formulas..

```
H1 --> =IF(G1="N/A",0,1)
H2 --> =IF(G2="N/A",H1,H1+1)
J1 --> =IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(I1,H:H,0)),"")
```

rag H2 + J1 downwards. some running numbers..

```
I1 --> 1
I2 --> 2
I3 --> 3
I4 --> 4 and so on..
```

Hope Column J is what you're looking for..  (:

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.. what does this do for me?

Comment: "I'd like those "N/A" rows to hide " <-- You'll get all the column G Narrative!C29 values, skipping the "N/A" rows. || Btw, I'm reproducing this without any sample data.. **just** the formula you shared.. I'm also assuming that there is no header in your data (1st data is located @ G1, second @ G2, no column title..) . Without sample data/screenshot, all of us here can best work with assumptions of the data structure/format. ( :

Comment: Another way of looking at this.. I don't have a one-line formula or vba script to "remove" the "N/A" rows. I need 3 columns (2 helper + 1 result) to achieve this feat. If you get stuck at understanding the steps/formula.. just buzz it here.. ( : || IMHO I'm not the best (skill) person here, but I work my way of using excel without vba or array formulas.. and here I am, with the best shot I've got. /(^_^)\

Comment: I just tried this in my spreadsheet. It does get rid of the "N/A", but it doesn't hide the rows. Just creates a blank space.

Comment: Yup, It doesn't. You'll need vba if you want to do it in the same sheet. || My workaround is .. to 'load' column A to F data to column K to P using `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(I1,$H:$H,0)),"")`. Then just 'map'  the result in column J to P in an "IntendedOutput" sheet.. I'll be as if the 'skipped' row was never there.. here is my [sample](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EcR5CPdus6BHj9h6kn8VhIsBgXfJcyuEUOBscLpbs7daBA?e=odtHdh) file.